# How can I parse command argument from the output of another bash command?

Tags: bash, ls

So imagine I run `ls foo` and get like

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
...
```

and then I'd like to run `script.sh --name aaa` that output another group of lines. What I wanna do is to merge the output of

- `script.sh --name aaa`
- `script.sh --name bbb`
- `script.sh --name ccc`
  ...

and pipe it with `wc -l` to compute the total number of lines in the output.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0):

Use `find -exec`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec script.sh {} \; | wc -l
```

https://linux.die.net/man/1/find